# Breadth First Search falling one index short of desired outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a bread-first search algorithm in Python to find the shortest path from the top left corner of a matrix (2d list) and the number 9, wherever it may fall in the matrix. For some reason when I run the code below with the included print statements, my x coordinate will outcome correctly (reached index 5 against desired 5). However, my y coordinate continues to be one index short (e.g. need 7 and it stops at 6). Additionally, when I print the queue, it's not empty but for some reason the function still ends. So, I don't understand why the code is exiting if neither criteria has been met (i.e. queue is empty or our desired coordinates have been found).

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque


def shortest_path(maze):
    num_rows = len(maze)
    num_cols = len(maze[0])

row_moves = [1, -1, 0, 0]
col_moves = [0, 0, 1, -1]

# Convert maze to an array and use numpy to find coordinates of our goal, which is the 9.
maze_to_matrix = np.array(maze)
destination = np.where(maze_to_matrix == 9)
destination_x, destination_y = destination[1][0], destination[0][0]

def is_valid_move(matrix, visited, y, x):
    return (y >= 0) and (y < num_rows) and (x >= 0) and (x < num_cols) \
           and matrix[y][x] == 1 and not visited[y][x]


def bfs(matrix, dest_y, dest_x):

    # Construct matrix to keep track of visited cells.
    visited = [[False for x in range(num_cols)] for y in range(num_rows)]

    # Mark our origin as visited.
    # Our origin is always the top left node.
    visited[0][0] = True

    # Create an empty queue to keep track of our nodes to visit.
    queue = deque()

    # Append our starting coordinates and its minimum distance from the source to our queue.
    # First number is y coordinate, or outer list index.
    # Second number is x coordinate, or inner list index.
    queue.append((0, 0, 0))

    # Store the length of the longest path from source to destination
    min_dist = float('inf')

    # Pull most recently visited node off queue and determine if neighbouring
    # nodes are accessible. Continue until no valid unvisited nodes remain.
    while queue:
        (y, x, dist) = queue.popleft()
        print(f'y: {y} and dest_y: {dest_y}')
        print(f'x: {x} and dest_x: {dest_x}')

        # If our destination is found then break the loop and return value.
        if y == dest_y and x == dest_x:
            min_dist = dist
            break

        # Check for all possible movement directions from current (x, y)
        # and add valid movements to our queue.
        for i in range(4):
            if is_valid_move(matrix, visited, y + row_moves[i], x + col_moves[i]):
                visited[y + row_moves[i]][x + col_moves[i]] = True
                queue.append((y + row_moves[i], x + col_moves[i], dist + 1))
                print(queue)

    if min_dist != float('inf'):
        return min_dist
    else:
        return "Desired destination can't be reached from given origin points."

return bfs(maze, destination_y, destination_x)


maze = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0]
]

print(shortest_path(maze))

# Outputting y: 6 and dest_y: 7 x: 5 and dest_x: 5 and the queue is full.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot... In my is_valid_move function I was only counting spaces within the matrix where value is 1, which means our goal of 9 won't ever be valid.

So the is_valid_function should look like this:

```
return (y >= 0) and (y < num_rows) and (x >= 0) and (x < num_cols) \
           and (matrix[y][x] == 1 or matrix[y][x] == 9) and not visited[y][x]
```